# Ethereum Wallet also other currency?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Can I also save other currency like  monero or dash in the Ethereum Wallet ?If yes  I would really appreciate some guideline or advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the Ethereum Wallet currently does not support currencies like Dash or Monero.

However, it does support EIP 20 compliant tokens, which can be pegged to other currencies using BTC Relay type SPV contracts